Is there any survey on the research related to computation of paths in graphs that are subject to fuel minimization?
I would suspect there are a few papers on the subject of fuel minimization that utilize linear programming formulations but are there any surveys on the research done in the computation of paths on graphs that use minimal fuel and are subject to further constraints that are related to real life fuel minimization in vehicles?

A fuel minimisation objective is common in so-called "green" vehicle routing problems. A review of the literature up to 2020-ish is given in Asghari et al. (2021). That could be a good starting point?
